# How can I display a sort of Binary Tree of collatz conjecture?

Tags: c++, math, console

I have created a program that generates a linked list of elements of collatz conjecture's "tree" as shown below:

[image: Collatz tree]

I want my linked list to be displayed in terminal Something like this:

```
  1  
  |  
  2  
  |  
  4  
  |  
  8  
  |  
 16  
  |   \  
 32    5  
  |    |  
 64   10
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

[This](https://github.com/adiultra/CollatzRsrch/blob/master/cop.cpp) is the code I have created for generating the series.

Note:

- splitter is the number that yields two numbers that point to it.
- if a number is not splitter it will have odd pointer as NULL

Comment: Could you display a part of the provided "tree" to terminal format ? What is the link between the text displayed (as "`Merge pull request ...`") and data generated by your software ?

Comment: That is I need numbers connected by the lines so it presents a visual way of seeing the connections

Comment: Could the code be in another language, such as Python?

Comment: Yes I just need the logic and if possible please also try to explain how that code works

Comment: Under the value `16`, the initial graphic has the branch `5` to the left of `32`, but in your example console output you have the branch `5` to the right of `32`. Which do you want? It makes a significant difference in my code (which is partially done).

Comment: Any one just be consistent with even and odd branching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While waiting the Python solution promised by @RoryDaulton, here is a 100% std C++ solution to create a Console Tree based to the Binary Tree algorithm.

**Step 1** - before adding the `ConsoleTree class`, it is necessary to add some element in the existing algorithm.

> Add a global `ndigit` integer to auto-size the length of
>   tree-branches.

```
int limit, total = 1;
int ndigit = 1; // minimum number of digit
```

> Add a field `layer` integer to store the branch position.

```
struct num {
    int n;
    int layer; // store the layer (start from 0)
    num *even;
    num *odd;
};
```

> Extract the greater value to be displayed to compute the number of
>   digit.

```
num *newnum(int x=1) {
    num *t = new num;

    t->n =x;
    ndigit = max(ndigit,x); // keep the greater value
    t->layer = 0;
    t->even=NULL;
    t->odd=NULL;
    return t;
}
```

> Add in the `generator()` function the layer value.

```
    //...
    en->layer = front->layer + 1; // next layer on even
    on->layer = front->layer + 1; // next layer on odd
    front -> even = en;
    front -> odd = on;
    //...
    t->layer = front->layer + 1; // next layer
    front -> even = t;
    //...
```

**Step 2** - the `ConsoleTree class` to manage numbers and branches of the tree.

```
class ConsoleTree {
private:
    int iSize;
    string *sDigitLines;
    string *sTreeLines;
protected:
    string FmtInt(int ival,int idigit,char cFill);
    string FmtTree(int idigit, bool bBranch);
    string ShiftRight(string& sLine, int ipos, int idigit);
public:
    ConsoleTree(int iLimit);
    ~ConsoleTree();
    int NbDigit(int x);
    void Make(num *pTree);
    void Print();
};

// Constructor to allocate the number of lines to be displayed
// sDigitLines array is dedicated to numbers
// sTreeLines array is dedicated to branches
ConsoleTree::ConsoleTree(int iLimit)
{
    iSize = iLimit+1;
    sDigitLines = new string[iSize];
    sTreeLines = new string[iSize];
}

// delete arrays
ConsoleTree::~ConsoleTree()
{
    delete[] sDigitLines;
    delete[] sTreeLines;
}

// format the numbers for sDigitLines
string ConsoleTree::FmtInt(int ival,int idigit,char cFill)
{
    ostringstream strStream;

    strStream << std::setfill(cFill) << std::setw(idigit) << (ival);
    return (strStream.str());
}

// format the tree & branches for sTreeLines
string ConsoleTree::FmtTree(int idigit, bool bBranch)
{
    ostringstream strStream;

    strStream << std::string(idigit-1, ' ') << "|";
    if (bBranch) strStream << std::string(idigit-2, '-') << "\\ ";
    return (strStream.str());
}

// Shift numbers & branches when adding new branches
string ConsoleTree::ShiftRight(string& sLine, int ipos, int idigit)
{
    int ilen = sLine.length();
    string sTemp;

    sTemp = sLine.substr(0,ipos);
    if ((ilen>ipos) && (sLine[ipos]=='-')) {
        sTemp += string(idigit, '-');
    }
    else {
        sTemp += string(idigit, ' ');
    }
    if (ilen>ipos) {
        sTemp += sLine.substr(ipos,ilen);
    }
    sLine = sTemp;
    return (sLine);
}

// compute the number of digit
int ConsoleTree::NbDigit(int x)
{
    ostringstream stmp;

    stmp << x;
    return (stmp.str().length()+1);
}

// recurrent function to create tree with numbers and branches
void ConsoleTree::Make(num *pn)
{
    int iLevel,iLen,iCut;
    string sTemp;

    while (pn!=NULL) {
        iLevel = pn->layer;
        sDigitLines[iLevel] += FmtInt(pn->n,ndigit,' ');
        if (pn->odd!=NULL) {
            iCut = sTreeLines[iLevel].length()+ndigit;
            sTreeLines[iLevel] += FmtTree(ndigit,true);
            for(int i=0;i<iLevel;i++) {
                sDigitLines[i] = ShiftRight(sDigitLines[i],iCut,ndigit);
                sTreeLines[i] = ShiftRight(sTreeLines[i],iCut,ndigit);
            }
            sDigitLines[iLevel] = ShiftRight(sDigitLines[iLevel],iCut,ndigit);
            Make(pn->odd);
        }
        else {
            sTreeLines[iLevel] += FmtTree(ndigit,false);
        }
        pn = pn->even;
    }
}

void ConsoleTree::Print()
{
    int iLimit = iSize -1;

    cout << "treeview" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<iLimit;i++) {
        cout << sDigitLines[i] << endl;
        cout << sTreeLines[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << sDigitLines[iLimit] << endl;
}
```

**Step 3** - Then modify `main()` function to display the tree after using `generator()`.

```
int main() {
    limit = 12; // define the height of the tree
    ndigit = 0;

    generator();

    num *pn = start; // first node of the binary-tree

    ConsoleTree myTree(limit);

    ndigit = myTree.NbDigit(ndigit);
    myTree.Make(pn);
    myTree.Print();

    cout << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Step 4** - output sample (limit = 12)

```
    1
    |
    2
    |
    4
    |
    8
    |
   16
    |-----------------------\
    5                       32
    |                        |
   10                       64
    |---\                    |---\
    3   20                  21  128
    |    |                   |    |
    6   40                  42  256
    |    |--------\          |    |--------\
   12   13        80        84   85       512
    |    |         |         |    |         |
   24   26       160       168  170      1024
    |    |         |---\     |    |         |---\
   48   52        53  320  336  340       341 2048
    |    |---\     |    |    |    |---\     |    |
   96   17  104  106  640  672  113  680  682 4096
```

**Enhancement** - change the look of the Console Tree by using semi-graphic extended ASCII characters

> In the `ConsoleTree::FmtTree()` function, use a set of 4 extended
>   ASCII { 195, 179 & 196, 191 }.

```
#ifdef EXTEND_ASCII
    strStream << string(idigit-1, ' ') << string(1,((bBranch)?(195):(179)));
    if (bBranch) strStream << string(idigit-1, 196) << string(1, 191);
#else
    strStream << std::string(idigit-1, ' ') << "|";
    if (bBranch) strStream << std::string(idigit-2, '-') << "\\ ";
#endif
```

> In the `ConsoleTree::ShiftRight()` function, use the extended ASCII
>   196 instead of `'-'`.

```
#ifdef EXTEND_ASCII
    // Warning: 196 is used as unsigned char ==> cast
    if ((ilen>ipos) && ((unsigned char)sLine[ipos]==196)) {
        sTemp += string(idigit, 196);
    }
#else
    if ((ilen>ipos) && (sLine[ipos]=='-')) {
        sTemp += string(idigit, '-');
    }
#endif
```

> And a sample of output (limit = 7)

```
   1
   │
   2
   │
   4
   │
   8
   │
  16
   ├───────┐
   5      32
   │       │
  10      64
   ├───┐   ├───┐
   3  20  21 128
```

Comment: That's a real lot of stuff for me but I will try hard to understand it... Thanks a lot

Comment: @Adityaultra to enhance the display, I have added an alternate solution using semi-graphic ASCII characters ("English Set " from 128 to 255).

Answer (score 2):

Here is Python code to print the Collatz binary tree to the console. The first section filling out the Collatz tree is recursive. The second second printing the structure is not recursive and I am not satisfied with that code--but it does what I wanted. The printing could be "kerned" to move some columns closer together and same some horizontal space. If you want the columns ordered as in your sample output, swap the `ndiv3` and `2*n` parameters in the large `if` section of routine `fillthe rest()`.

```
"""Print a representation of a Collatz binary tree to the console."""

# Define each column (a list) in `columns`.
STARTROW = 0    # index of zero-based row where a column starts (int)
WIDTH = 1       # index of char width of max number in the column so far (int)
NUMBERS = 2     # index of the numbers in the column (list of ints)

def numstr(num):
    """Return a number string, properly formatted with commas"""
    return '{:,}'.format(num)

def fillnewcolumn(num, row, columns, dontuse, limit):
    """Fill a new column, starting with number `num` in row `row` of
    the partially-filled structure 'columns', not using the numbers in
    `dontuse`, up to row 'limit'."""
    dontuse.add(num)  # mark num as used
    columns.append([row, len(numstr(num)), [num]])  # top non-blank row of col
    filltherest(row, columns, dontuse, limit)  # keep going

def filloldcolumn(num, row, columns, dontuse, limit):
    """Fill the old column, starting with number `num` in row `row` of
    the partially-filled structure 'columns', not using the numbers in
    `dontuse`, up to row 'limit'."""
    dontuse.add(num)  # mark num as used
    thiscolumn = columns[-1]  # last column so far
    thiscolumn[WIDTH] = max(thiscolumn[WIDTH], len(numstr(num)))
    thiscolumn[NUMBERS].append(num)  # add num to column
    filltherest(row, columns, dontuse, limit)  # keep going

def filltherest(row, columns, dontuse, limit):
    """Fill the rest of the partially-filled structure 'columns' which
    already has used the numbers in `used`, from row 'row' in column
    `col`."""
    if limit <= 1:
        return
    thiscolumn = columns[-1]  # last column so far
    n = thiscolumn[NUMBERS][-1]  # last number in this column
    ndiv3, nmod3 = divmod(n, 3)
    if nmod3 == 1 and ndiv3 % 2 != 0 and ndiv3 not in dontuse:  # two branches
        filloldcolumn(ndiv3, row+1, columns, dontuse, limit-1)
        fillnewcolumn(2*n, row+1, columns, dontuse, limit-1)
    else:  # one branch from here
        filloldcolumn(2*n, row+1, columns, dontuse, limit-1)

limit = int(input('How many levels of Collatz to print? '))

# Fill the structure.
columns = []            # information for the overall structure to print
dontuse = {0}           # numbers to not add to the structure
fillnewcolumn(1, 0, columns, dontuse, limit)

# Print the structure to the console.
for row in range(limit):
    numline = ''
    diagline = ''
    for column in columns:
        startingrow = column[STARTROW]
        numwidth = column[WIDTH]
        if startingrow <= row:
            nstr = numstr(column[NUMBERS][row-startingrow])
            numline += nstr.rjust(numwidth) + ' '
            if startingrow == row:
                blanks = ' ' * (len(nstr) + 1)
                oldlinesize = len(numline)
                diagline = diagline.rstrip() + '\\'
                dellinesize = oldlinesize - len(diagline)
                diagline += blanks.rjust(dellinesize, '_')
            else:
                diagline += '|'.rjust(numwidth) + ' '
        else:
            numline += ''.rjust(numwidth) + ' '
            diagline += ''.rjust(numwidth) + ' '
    if row > 0:
        print(diagline.rstrip())
    print(numline.rstrip())
```

Here is the output for 15 lines from the above code.

```
  1
  |
  2
  |
  4
  |
  8
  |
 16
  |\___________________________________
  5                                    32
  |                                     |
 10                                    64
  |\                                    |\
  3 20                                 21 128
  |  |                                  |   |
  6 40                                 42 256
  |  |\____________                     |   |\__________________
 12 13             80                  84  85                   512
  |  |              |                   |   |                     |
 24 26            160                 168 170                 1,024
  |  |              |\____              |   |                     |\______
 48 52             53     320         336 340                   341       2,048
  |  |\___          |       |           |   |\______              |           |
 96 17    104     106     640         672 113       680         682       4,096
  |  |      |       |\      |\          |   |         |           |\          |\_
192 34    208      35 212 213 1,280 1,344 226     1,360         227 1,364 1,365  8,192
  |  |\     |\      |   |   |     |     |   |\        |\          |     |     |      |
384 11 68  69 416  70 424 426 2,560 2,688  75 452   453 2,720   454 2,728 2,730 16,384
```

And here is the output for 15 lines if you switch the order of the columns. The pattern is more regular and it ends up taking less horizontal space.

```
     1
     |
     2
     |
     4
     |
     8
     |
    16
     |\___________________________________________
    32                                            5
     |                                            |
    64                                           10
     |\____________________________________       |\__________________________
   128                                     21    20                           3
     |                                      |     |                           |
   256                                     42    40                           6
     |\___________________                  |     |\____________              |
   512                    85               84    80             13           12
     |                     |                |     |              |            |
 1,024                   170              168   160             26           24
     |\________            |                |     |\_____        |            |
 2,048         341       340              336   320      53     52           48
     |           |         |\____           |     |       |      |\___        |
 4,096         682       680     113      672   640     106    104    17     96
     |\          |\        |       |        |     |\      |\     |     |      |
 8,192 1,365 1,364 227 1,360     226    1,344 1,280 213 212 35 208    34    192
     |     |     |   |     |\      |\       |     |   |   |  |   |\    |\     |
16,384 2,730 2,728 454 2,720 453 452 75 2,688 2,560 426 424 70 416 69 68 11 384
```